# Create title page layout

Tags: titles, layout

I would like to use latex. However, I would like to use a slightly different layout.
The layout contains two separate areas, which are coloured differently. They are separated by a thick white bar and there is a white frame around them.

How could I create such a template in Latex?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{2cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\graphicspath{{pic/}} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- more modern than 'url'
\usepackage[]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
    
    
        \normalfont \normalsize 
        \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
        \center
        {\LARGE \textsc{Some Text}} \\[4ex]
        {\Large Another Text}\\
           \vspace*{8ex}
        \HRule \\[0.4cm]
        { \huge \bfseries More Text}\\[0.4cm] 
        \HRule \\[1.5cm]
          \vspace*{8ex}
        {\Large Name 1001\\
                Name 100\\}

    \vspace*{16ex}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\large
        Max Power \\
        Frank Boy \\
        \vspace*{4ex}
        Small Text \\}
    \end{flushleft} 
        
        
        
    \end{titlepage}
    
    

    
\newpage



\end{document}
```

What I want

[image]

Comment: Maybe the `titling` package could help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of very customised title page is best done directly in `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{topcolour}{RGB}{0,37,118}
\definecolor{bottomcolour}{RGB}{92,142,254}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill [topcolour] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.east) 
      node [white, align=center, yshift=5mm, text width=15cm,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge] at (current path bounding box)
      {\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{example-image}

       \bigskip

       Title};
    \fill [bottomcolour] (current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \draw [white, line width=2mm] ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north west)
      rectangle ([shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]current page.south east)
      node [white, align=left, anchor=south west, text width=15cm,
      font=\sffamily\Large, inner sep=5mm]
      at (current path bounding box.south west)
      {\textbf{\huge Something in bold}

       \medskip
       
       This is normal text

       \medskip

       More normal text but with more spaces \\
       Name xy 100 \\
       Name zz 101

       \bigskip

       Max Power \\
       Frank Boy

       \bigskip

       \textbf{\LARGE Some bold text but smaller}

       \bigskip

       {\large Small text} \\
       {\large And again small text}};
     \node [fill=white, font=\sffamily\huge, align=center, text
       width=\paperwidth-2cm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=5cm]
        at (current page)
       {\textbf{Subtitle 2}

        \bigskip

        {\LARGE Subtitle 1}};
      \node [anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt, shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]
        at (current page.south east)
        {\includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!!